# Troubleshooting Build Error in MiDaS ROS1 Package

Tags: c++, camera, ros

I am trying to build the ROS1 package provided by [MiDaS](https://github.com/isl-org/MiDaS) and while building it I am getting this compilation error.

```
Scanning dependencies of target midas_cpp
[ 50%] Building CXX object midas_cpp/CMakeFiles/midas_cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable midas_cpp
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.2, needed by /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libcv_bridge.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgcodecs.so.408
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.408, needed by /home/ketan/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.8.0, may conflict with libopencv_core.so.4.2
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/midas_cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Size_<int>, int, void*, unsigned long)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatC2ENS_5Size_IiEEiPvm[_ZN2cv3MatC5ENS_5Size_IiEEiPvm]+0x155): undefined reference to `cv::error(int, std::string const&, char const*, char const*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatC2ENS_5Size_IiEEiPvm[_ZN2cv3MatC5ENS_5Size_IiEEiPvm]+0x194): undefined reference to `cv::error(int, std::string const&, char const*, char const*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/midas_cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `Midas::imageCb(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5Midas7imageCbERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEE[_ZN5Midas7imageCbERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEE]+0x40): undefined reference to `cv_bridge::toCvCopy(boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, std::string const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5Midas7imageCbERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEE[_ZN5Midas7imageCbERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEE]+0x29eb): undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation(ros::console::LogLocation*, std::string const&, ros::console::levels::Level)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5Midas7imageCbERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEE[_ZN5Midas7imageCbERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKN11sensor_msgs6Image_ISaIvEEEEE]+0x2c67): undefined reference to `ros::console::initializeLogLocation(ros::console::LogLocation*, std::string const&, ros::console::levels::Level)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/midas_cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `Midas::Midas()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x8d): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::string const&, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x1ed): undefined reference to `ros::param::has(std::string const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x200): undefined reference to `ros::param::get(std::string const&, std::string&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x26f): undefined reference to `ros::param::has(std::string const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x282): undefined reference to `ros::param::get(std::string const&, std::string&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x2f1): undefined reference to `ros::param::has(std::string const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x304): undefined reference to `ros::param::get(std::string const&, std::string&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x36b): undefined reference to `ros::param::has(std::string const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x3b3): undefined reference to `ros::param::has(std::string const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x3fe): undefined reference to `ros::param::has(std::string const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x5e6): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle(std::string const&, std::map<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, std::string> > > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x817): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::hasParam(std::string const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x831): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::getParam(std::string const&, std::string&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x8d7): undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::subscribe(std::string const&, unsigned int, boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)> const&, boost::shared_ptr<void> const&, image_transport::TransportHints const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0xaa2): undefined reference to `image_transport::ImageTransport::advertise(std::string const&, unsigned int, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x12a2): undefined reference to `ros::param::get(std::string const&, int&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x12ea): undefined reference to `ros::param::get(std::string const&, int&)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN5MidasC2Ev[_ZN5MidasC5Ev]+0x1332): undefined reference to `ros::param::get(std::string const&, bool&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/midas_cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x52): undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::string const&, unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/libgdal.so.26: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBATileExt@LIBTIFF_4.0'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/libgdal.so.26: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAStripExt@LIBTIFF_4.0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [midas_cpp/CMakeFiles/midas_cpp.dir/build.make:190: midas_cpp/midas_cpp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:833: midas_cpp/CMakeFiles/midas_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed
```

I've checked that libtiff5.so library is installed. and the cmake paths are set properly.

This is what I am doing,

```
export Torch_DIR=/home/ketan/miniconda3/envs/midas-py310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/share/cmake/Torch
export CUDACXX=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/nvcc

catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCUDNN_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ketan/miniconda3/envs/midas-py310/lib/libcudnn.so -DCUDNN_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/ketan/miniconda3/pkgs/cudnn-8.9.2.26-cuda11_0/include -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.7m
```

Is there a dependency issue? Version mismatch? I couldn't figure out.